# Error 3141 and Run-Time error while running Access Macro

Tags: vba, ms-access

I received an error while trying to add a column to an report pushed to Excel.

Error 3141:

`The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.`

Then i immediately get:

```
Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set
```

When i Debug, it highlights `xlApp.Visible = True`

My code:

```
 On Error GoTo SubError

    'Dim xlApp As Object
    'Dim xlBook As Object
    'Dim xlSheet As Object


    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer

    'Show user work is being performed
    DoCmd.Hourglass (True)

    '*********************************************
    '              RETRIEVE DATA
    '*********************************************
    'SQL statement to retrieve data from database
    'SQL = "SELECT PartNo AS [Part Number], PartName AS [Part Name], " & _
    '"Price, SalePrice AS [Sale Price], " & _
    '"(Price - SalePrice) / Price AS Discount " & _
    '"FROM Parts " & _
    '"ORDER BY PartNo "

    SQL = "SELECT NewFSR.Date AS [FSR Date], NewFSR.RemitDate AS [Check Date], NewFSR.RemitNumber AS [Check Number], " & _
    "NewFSR.collamt AS [Check Amount], NewFSR.remitter AS From, " & _
    "NewFSR.purpose AS Purpose, NewFSR.appropriation AS Fund, NewFSR.fsrnum AS [FSR Number], " & _
    "NewFSR.[Deposit Date], NewFSR.[Agent Cashier], NewFSR.beneficiary AS Beneficiary, NewFSR.Comments, " & _
    "FROM NewFSR " & _
    "ORDER BY NewFSR.fsrnum "


    'Execute query and populate recordset
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

    'If no data, don't bother opening Excel, just quit
    If rs1.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data selected for export", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No data exported"
        GoTo SubExit
    End If

    '*********************************************
    '             BUILD SPREADSHEET
    '*********************************************
    'Create an instance of Excel and start building a spreadsheet

    'Early Binding
    Set xlApp = Excel.Application

    xlApp.Visible = False
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

    With xlSheet
        .Name = "Check Survey Log"
        .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 11

        'Set column widths
        .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 10
        .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 10
        .Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 25
        .Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 10
        .Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 30
        .Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 60
        .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 10
        .Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 10
        .Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 10
        .Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 10
        .Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 30
        .Columns("L").ColumnWidth = 60

        'Format columns
        '.Columns("C").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00"
        '.Columns("D").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00"
        '.Columns("F").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0#%;-#,##0.0#%"

        For cols = 0 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, cols + 1).Value = rs1.Fields(cols).Name
        Next

        'Copy data from recordset to sheet
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs1

    End With

SubExit:
On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    xlApp.Visible = True
    rs1.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Exit Sub

SubError:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.number & "= " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
        "An error occurred"
    GoTo SubExit
```

Please help!! Thanks.

Comment: `FROM` is a reserved word in SQL - don't use it as a field name. If you really want to, enclose it in [ ] characters: `[From]`. Also advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: That should read: `Set xlApp = New Excel.Application`.